# Colored bar above title in LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, templates, themes

I wrote an unofficial beamer template for my university. I put the beamer style file and example presentation on github: https://github.com/broesel007/dshsbeamer

Here my question: How can I add a colored bar (e.g. red) above the blue title bar? I also would like to add the logo of our institute in that bar. How can I do that? Any recommendations?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `headline` template appropriately. The `separation line` color allows you to define the background color for the new bar; I set it to `myred`, where I used

```
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{225,0,76}
```

Of course, use the color that best suits your needs. I also defined a `\Ulogo` command that allows you to introduce the University logo centered in this bar; the usage of this command is similar to that of `\titlegraphic`:

```
\Ulogo{\includegraphics[height=2ex,width=3cm]{<image file>}}
```

A complete example (since no information was provided about dimensions of the new bar and position of the logo, I used some sensible values, but you can change those according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{dshsbeamer}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\LARGE,series=\bfseries}

% color definitions
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{spohoblue}{RGB}{0, 83, 146}
\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{225,0,76}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=myred}
\newcommand\Ulogo[1]{\def\insertUlogo{#1}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\the\@tempdima,ht=4ex,dp=0ex]{separation line}
  \vbox{}\vskip-10pt
  \hfill\insertUlogo\hfill\null
  \vskip0.5ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\title[Short title]{An unofficial beamer template for the German Sport University Cologne}
\author[Short author]{Magnus Metz}
\institute[The Institute of Advanced Study]
{Institute of Sport Economics and Sport Management \\
German Sport University Cologne \\
}
\Ulogo{\includegraphics[height=2ex,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First slide}
A test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do I need to do, if I want to have the logo of the University as high as the red separation line and aligned to the right?

Thank you very much for further informations!

Sincerely yours,

broesel